# Tiny "upvote arrow" on user profiles on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, mobile-web

[image]

On mobile, on certain user profiles, there's a little comment-upvote type arrow. I tapped it repeatedly(since tapping comment upvotes on mobile doesn't always work--you miss at times) just to see what it does, and it wouldn't work.

Doing some investigation on desktop, I realized that it's not supposed to do anything. More investigation revealed that it was part of the of the user bio (and shows up as a plain arrow when the bio is empty):

[image]

Sort of inconsequential, but this could be improved to be less confusing.

Though this probably will be declined since it complicates mobile site code :/

Comment: Problem: Your user bio is empty. Solution: Fill in your user bio.

Comment: @TheE not MY bio. Others' bio.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed and will be deployed in the next builds (`rev 2235` on meta and `rev 1600` on main)